# Scala: missing implicit generic parameter shapeless.LabelledGeneric.Aux[T,L], how to provide it?

Tags: postgresql, scala, generics, shapeless, finagle

I'm writing code for working with DB with [finagle-postgres](https://github.com/finagle/finagle-postgres), I have mappers and sure I want to move common parts of code, as much as I can, to generic Mapper.

So, for example, I have Mapper

```
case class ProcessState(
  ...
)

class ProcessStateMapper(client: PostgresClient)
  extends EntityMapper[ProcessState]("process_state", client)(rowDecoder) {

  ...

  def create(state: ProcessState): Future[ProcessState] = {
    val fields = Updates(state)
    val columnNames = fields.updates.map(_._1).mkString(", ")
    val placeholders = (1 to fields.updates.size).map(i => s"$$$i").mkString(", ")
    for {
      inserted <- client.prepareAndExecute(
        s"INSERT INTO $tableName ($columnNames) VALUES ($placeholders)", fields.params: _*)
    } yield {
      require(inserted > 0, s"Failed to create $tableName: $state")
      state
    }
  }

}
```

This create method works fine, `Updates` requires implicit `shapeless.LabelledGeneric.Aux[T,L]`, and in this context it finds it.

But if I move method to generic class, because of type erasure, it can't find implicit value...

```
abstract class EntityMapper[T <: Product](
  val tableName: String, val client: PostgresClient)(
  implicit val rowDecoder: RowDecoder[T]) {

  ...

  def create(state: T): Future[T] = {
    val fields = Updates(state)
    val columnNames = fields.updates.map(_._1).mkString(", ")
    val placeholders = (1 to fields.updates.size).map(i => s"$$$i").mkString(", ")
    for {
      inserted <- client.prepareAndExecute(
        s"INSERT INTO $tableName ($columnNames) VALUES ($placeholders)", fields.params: _*)
    } yield {
      require(inserted > 0, s"Failed to create $tableName: $state")
      state
    }
  }
}
```

So this code doesn't compile with error

```
could not find implicit value for parameter gen: shapeless.LabelledGeneric.Aux[T,L]
    val fields = Updates(state)
```

So I try to provide this param

```
abstract class EntityMapper[T <: Product](
  val tableName: String, val client: PostgresClient)(
  implicit val rowDecoder: RowDecoder[T], val lgen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[T, _]) {
  ...
}

class ProcessStateMapper(client: PostgresClient)
  extends EntityMapper[ProcessState]("process_state", client)(rowDecoder, ProcessStateMapper.lgen) {
  ...
}

object ProcessStateMapper {
  ...

  val lgen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[ProcessState, _] = LabelledGeneric[ProcessState]
}
```

But it doesn't work, I tried some other ways of providing it, but they all failed. Do you know what's the proper way of doing this?

Comment: You probably do not want to interact directly with **Shapeless** but rather using some [**Typeclass**](https://tpolecat.github.io/2013/10/12/typeclass.html) provided by the library. Thus instead of `EntityMapper[T <: Product]` you want `EntityMapper[T : SomeTypeClass]` maybe is that `Mapper` you mentioned at the beginning of the question.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks for the link! I'm pretty new in Scala, so it's really helpful. But I don't understand what do you mean... There's a typeclass `HList`, but I can't use it as bound, because case class doesn't implement it, so could you please explain more concrete?

Comment: Ok so first, I personally would recommend you to become familiar with the **typeclass** pattern _(and maybe more with the language in general)_, especially since the idea of the pattern is that classes do not need to directly implement the interface, maybe [this](https://gist.github.com/BalmungSan/c19557030181c0dc36533f3de7d7abf4) would help. - Now, `HList` is not really a **typeclass** but rather a mechanism to automatically and generically derive **typeclasses** instance for **case classes**, but that is something library authors use; not really users.

Comment: That is why I say that you should not worry about asking for the `HList` but rather asking for the **typeclass** that way whoever calls you need to provide the **typeclass** which may be done by automatically derivating through an `HList` under the hood without that person noticing it.

Comment: @wackloner *"because of type erasure, it can't find implicit value"* Type erasure occurs after implicit resolution so can't be relevant to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Updates#apply`](https://github.com/finagle/finagle-postgres/blob/096742b506c05253ed6418de315d9948fdf65758/finagle-postgres-shapeless/src/main/scala/com/twitter/finagle/postgres/generic/Updates.scala#L29) requires more than just a `LabelledGeneric.Aux[P, L]`.
The complete signature is:

```scala
def apply[P <: Product, L <: HList, MP <: HList](p: P)(implicit
    gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[P, L],
    mapper: Mapper.Aux[toLabelledParam.type, L, MP],
    toList: ToList[MP, (String, Param[_])],
    columnNamer: ColumnNamer
  ): Updates
```

In order to be able to call the function, you need to add all these implicit parameters to your class as well. And since the `L` and `MP` type parameters need to be in scope too, you need to add them as type parameters for your class as well. So you end up with this:

```scala
abstract class EntityMapper[P <: Product, L <: HList, MP <: HList](
  val tableName: String, val client: PostgresClient)(
  implicit rowDecoder: RowDecoder[T],
           gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[P, L],
           mapper: Mapper.Aux[toLabelledParam.type, L, MP],
           toList: ToList[MP, (String, Param[_])],
           columnNamer: ColumnNamer) {
```

This stinks! Not only because of all of those implicits, but also because now you have two completely meaningless type parameters in your class.

But you can work around that with some implicits:

```scala
trait Updatable[P <: Product] {
  def apply(p: P): Updates
}

object Updatable {
  implicit def instance[P <: Product, L <: HList, MP <: HList](
    implicit gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[P, L],
             mapper: Mapper.Aux[toLabelledParam.type, L, MP],
             toList: ToList[MP, (String, Param[_])],
             columnNamer: ColumnNamer): Updatable[P] = new Updatable[P] {
    def apply(p: P): Updates = Updates(p)
  }
}
```

And now you can write your `EntityMapper` like so:

```scala
abstract class EntityMapper[T <: Product](
  val tableName: String,
  val client: PostgresClient)(
  implicit updatable: Updatable[T]) {
  …
  def create(state: T): Future[T] = {
    val fields = updatable(state)
    …
  }
  …
}
```